# Pushing tags/branches to a new remote in Git?

Tags: git

I have a Git repository with the following branches/tags:

```
$ git show-ref
8797bba0d098c30fc233c6aba150fd5b925ae8f1 refs/heads/experiment
8797bba0d098c30fc233c6aba150fd5b925ae8f1 refs/heads/master
8797bba0d098c30fc233c6aba150fd5b925ae8f1 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
f7c967b3e59a922870e5c1b4a9b95e2c98f27086 refs/remotes/origin/develop
8797bba0d098c30fc233c6aba150fd5b925ae8f1 refs/remotes/origin/master
86bebfb80813123268ae5399194ae6e7b79a1b0b refs/remotes/origin/myfeature
f7c967b3e59a922870e5c1b4a9b95e2c98f27086 refs/remotes/origin/snapshot
526db3844560df31a19074a9ab4727f6b2e5acbb refs/tags/cpp.pom-0.0.1
```

**First question:** Can all the above tags/branches be reached from the original master branch?

**Second question:** What happens when I push a single of these branches/tags to a brand new remote? Example:

I have created a new remote/empty Git Repository and added that as a remote on the above git repository containing the above branches/tags. I have then pushed ONLY the above tag: **refs/tags/cpp.pom-0.0.1** to the new remote. Below is the result:

[image]

If all branches/tags can be reached from master can´t I mess something up here? E.g. pushing a tag/label to some history not yet pushed to the new remote?

Answer (score 0):

> Can all the above tags/branches be reached from the original master branch?

Well, not directly, but all branches have at least one common commit and all commits have at least one common (grand)parent: the initial commit. A branch in Git is actually a pointer to a commit and the concept of commits belonging to a branch in specific time in history is not present in Git; commits are considered to belong to a branch if they are in any part of its history. Therefore the initial commit is actually present in all branches.

> What happens when I push a single of these branches/tags to a brand new remote?

It will be there together with the whole history of that branch/tag (but not history of all branches/tags).

> If all branches/tags can be reached from master can´t I mess something up here? E.g. pushing a tag/label to some history not yet pushed to the new remote?

Unless you force-push some branches (which you should not do in shared repositories), no, you cannot.

Side note: it seems to me that you don't really get the concept of branches/tags in Git. They are just pointers to specific commits and don't contain any changes themselves. Each commit then contains changes and links to one or more parent commits, thus creating the whole history graph. So you may not have specific branch set in the repository (or it may point to different commit) but you may still have its commit there (and can find it using its commit hash) if it was pushed due to being part of history of a different branch/tag. When Git pushes some branch/tag, it actually pushes all commits of that branch/tag history that are not yet in the remote repository and then sets the branch/tag pointer to point to the correct commit. This makes it very robust and hard to break.

Comment: Ok I simply do not understand you reply to my first question :-) Lets assume only one remote called origin (default). If I follow each of the branches/tags back in time I will per definition of a branch/pointer/label in the Git Graph eventually end up in my initial commit on the master branch right?

Comment: Sorry, I have originally mixed in the answer origin branch and orignal repository; I have update the answer.

Comment: What I mean is is it possible to visit all commits/nodes/tags/branches from any given node/commit on the master branch? E.g. is it possible to run depth-first search (DFS) or breadth-first search (BFS) on a git Graph?

Comment: No, only parent commits are reachable, there is no reference from parent to child.